# Track success or failure for hive queries running through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hive

I am running few hive queries in a single shell script like below

```
#!/bin/bash  
HQLSource='/home/hql/'  
hive  -f $HQLSource/query1.hql               
hive  -f $HQLSource/query2.hql
```

`query1.hql` and `query2.hql` have statements to create a table and insert data - if anything fails, I would consider the whole .hql as failed. Can I write to a text file whether the queries are all successful or failed?

**Expected Output:**

```
query1.hql - Success  
query2.hql - Failed
```

Comment: you can check exit status for each command and accordingly write success, failure in file

Answer (score 4):

The exit code rom the previous command is stored in the variable `$?`. Any non-zero value is considered a failure of some kind.

```
#!/bin/bash  
HQLSource='/home/hql/'  
hive -f "$HQLSource/query1.hql"               
query1result=$?
hive -f "$HQLSource/query2.hql"               
query2result=$?
# do stuff with $query1result and $query2result
```

The exit code is also used by `if` statements to determine a code path, so you could also do this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
HQLSource='/home/hql/'  
if hive -f "$HQLSource/query1.hql"
then
    echo Query 1 succeeded
else
    echo Query 1 failed
fi
if hive -f "$HQLSource/query2.hql"
then
    echo Query 2 succeeded
else
    echo Query 2 failed
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do two checks with in bash file to know status of hql execution.

1. Return result should be equal to 0 else declare hql excution fail.

   ```
   beeline -u jdbc:hive2://IP:PORT -n USER -p PASSWORD -f hql_file.hql 2> ./hql_file.logs
   query1result=$?
   if [ $query1result -eq 0 ]; then
          # no issue
   fi
   ```
2. Scan generated log file for pattern Error/Exception, if pattern matches declare hql fail.

   ```
   for logfile in ./hql_file.logs; do
       errorFound="false"
       while read -r line; do
           # check for exception or error.Add grep search pattern based on need.
           excep=$(echo $line|grep "Error/|Exception")
           # if no space means no error or exception
           if [ -n "${excep##+([[:space:]])}" ]; then
               errorFound="true";                   
           fi
       done < "$logfile"
   done
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**I have checked and verified the code so use it without any doubt.**

1. Put each hive statement in a separate file e.g setup_step_4.hive
2. In the shell script call this file.
   **setup_step_4.hive**
   load data local inpath 'nyse.csv' into table nyse_data;

**code in shell script will look like this :**

```
hive -f setup_step_3.hive
query1result=$?
echo $query1result
if [ "$query1result" -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo "  Error."
      exit 4
      else 
      echo "Done.Successfully"
    fi

hive -f setup_step_4.hive
query1result=$?
echo $query1result
if [ "$query1result" -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo "  Error"
      exit 4
      else 
      echo "Done.Successfully"
    fi
```

**For example 
the step 3 executed successfully and 
the step 4 failed because file does not exists.**

**Output**

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
OK

Time taken: 1.413 seconds

0

***Done.Successfully***

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j.properties
OK

Time taken: 1.574 seconds

FAILED: SemanticException Line 3:23 Invalid path ''nyse.csv'': No files matching path file:/root/Data/nyse.csv

64

***Error,***